# Alien invasion movie, including the line: "We are the food"

Tags: story-identification, movie, hard-sci-fi, alien-invasion

I saw this sci-fi movie once on TV, around the second half of the 90's.

In this movie, a huge UFO was found near the North Pole (or was it the south?) and an expedition is called to go inside.

Inside the UFO, I remember they found a lot of test tubes containing fetuses. The fetuses were human-like and, I think, alive.

As soon as they handled some of the UFO controls, it started sending a signal to somewhere in the sky. Scientists started to analyze the signal and they interpreted it as saying something like "the food is ready". Later, they found some "plans" explaining how life was started on Earth and what will happen in the evolutionary process as we know it today.

They discover that everything happened as "they" planned; life on Earth started, evolved, civilization rose, cities were built, technology accelerated, we discovered and entered the UFO, handled the controls and sent the signal. All of this, predicted thousand of years ago. And... the most concerning part: we sent a signal to the beings that will use us as candies or part of a huge barbecue.

In the final scene, the Earth defense forces get their radars saturated by hundred of UFOs.

They don't show the extraterrestrials eating us, but that's implicit. No happy ending this time.

Did somebody watch this and can they tell me which story it is based on... or the movie name?

I asked some AI and it told me that this film is called *Independence Day*, which demonstrates that AI can make jokes too.

Comment: It demonstrates that, at the moment, artificial intelligence...isn't very.

Comment: https://irememberthismovie.com/80searly-90s-alien-movie-where-everything-on-earth-was-made-for-their-food/ - This guy might be looking for the same film

Comment: Current popular AI is good at generating plausible talk, images, music, but without any regards for the truth.

Comment: Yes, it was funny how the AI tried to convince me to accept Will Smith in this plot. In fact, the purpose of AI is to make you think its real, not to really help.

Comment: Sounds similar to [Alien vs Predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_vs._Predator_(film)), which came out in 2004.

Comment: At least the AI didn't make up a fake movie.

Comment: Out of curiosity I fed your question verbatim to ChatGPT and it said ... *The movie you're describing sounds like "The Arrival," a sci-fi film directed by David Twohy, released in 1996. In the movie, Charlie Sheen plays the main character, Zane Zaminski, who discovers a massive alien conspiracy involving signals from outer space and a plan to harvest humans. The film has the elements you mentioned, including a UFO found near the North Pole, the discovery of human-like fetuses, and the revelation of an alien plan for Earth's evolution. .*

Comment: (cont'd) *The movie does indeed take a darker turn with the implication of a threat to humanity rather than a happy ending* --- It seems that it got better with time. I have no idea if this is close to reality though.

Comment: @WoJ - That plot summary of _The Arrival_ (1996) starts off pretty accurate with the stuff about Charlie Sheen's character discovering an alien signal and conspiracy, but the stuff about the North Pole, human-like fetuses and an alien plan for human evolution is BS. See the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Arrival_(1996_film)) for a more detailed rundown of the plot.

Comment: @LogicDictates: these generative services are more convincing than my children when they claim that this is the other one that broke something. And this means they ARE convincing.

Answer (score 26):

Is this the TV-movie,  ***[Survivor](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0187534/)*** (1999)...?

> An Arctic oil rig crew discovers something strange far beneath the Earth's surface, which may or may not be responsible for the series of murders that begin to take place.

**What matches:**

- While drilling for oil, an oil rig crew discovers an alien spacecraft buried 57,000 feet beneath the surface of the Arctic.
- One of the main characters -- a geologist named Kat Holden -- is lowered into the vessel and finds hundreds of cylindrical chambers in the walls, at least one of which contains a human foetus. She also finds thousands of seeds filled with an "intense amino acid compound," and an unidentified device, which she takes with her when she's pulled back up to the surface.

> [image: Image of the interior of the alien vessel from "Survivor" (1999).]
>
> <sub>*Survivor* (1999)</sub>

- A discussion takes place between the main characters. Holden explains that the alien vessel has been buried beneath the Arctic for approximately one billion years, and proposes that the alien/s aboard it may have been responsible for the inception of life on Earth.
- The device brought up from the alien vessel is found to contain holographic blueprints of Earth's solar system, every lifeform on Earth, and the evolution and proliferation of man up to the Neolithic Era.

> [image: Image of holographic alien blueprints from "Survivor" (1999).]
>
> <sub>*Survivor* (1999)</sub>

- The main characters conclude that the alien/s planted the seeds of life on Earth in order to harvest humans as food at a later time. One line of dialogue is pretty close to that quoted in your question title:

> KAT HOLDEN: It's not God. It's a farmer.
>
> ADAM KING: Yeah. **We're the cattle.**
>
> <sub>*Survivor* (1999)</sub>

**What doesn't match:**

- While the alien/s had blueprints depicting the evolution of man up to the Neolithic Era, Holden speculates that they didn't intend for man to evolve beyond that point, which implies that they didn't predict the building of cities and stuff like that.
- Although a signal is sent to outer space -- which one of the main characters equates to a "dinner bell" being rung to let the aliens know that the "crop is grown" -- it isn't sent as a result of humans touching controls on the alien vessel. Rather, the vessel contained one surviving alien that made its way to the surface, killed some of the main characters, and planted an antenna-like device on the surface, which is what sent out the signal.
- The alien signal is never analysed. Its purpose is merely assumed.
- The antenna is destroyed by one of the main characters after a short while, and we never actually see any other aliens approaching, or arriving on, Earth. The ending of the film is ostensibly a happy one.

Comment: I would say "has to be this one", some details may have changed in my mind, but the last one... I am completely sure of this (UFOs approaching). I'll have to give a check to "Survivor", maybe I'm mixing two movies or something like that. Lot of thanks!

Comment: kind of like speilberg's war of the worlds which differed from other adaptations in that the martians had had plans for maybe millions of years.

Answer (score -1):

the movie is an episode from the Twilight Zone called To Serve Men
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Serve_Man_(The_Twilight_Zone)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in _why_ you believe this is what the OP is looking for? Any points that match the original question? A synopsis? Please see [answer] for some more information.

Comment: This doesn't match the description in the slightest.